# Need help/tools to compare SQL queries

Tags: sql, performance, text, compare

I have this comments table with over 4 million rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` 
(
     `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `gid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `userid` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
     `date` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
     `comment` text NOT NULL,
     `status` enum('on','alert') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'on',
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `gid_2` (`gid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

now I'm thinking about extracting the text-field to decrease the 400 MB and increase performance. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE commentstext 
(
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `comment` text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

but I'm not sure if this will perform better this way. I need to test this cases by using different queries (also). My results so far differ a lot. Between 0.001* - 3.321 sec. I'm not able to check this by querying in phpmyadmin.

Is there a better and easy way or tool to compare queries performance?

Comment: can you maybe explain a bit more about the queries that you think you need optimizing? show the code snippets maybe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215882/mysql-select-from-t1-t2-or-from-t1-join-t2-on

Comment: the queries are not as much important in this thread. I need to test different database structures. I've read about Super Smack, SysBench, mybench,... but I'm still looking for a less complicate solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I was looking for:

```
SELECT BENCHMARK(1000000000, (
SELECT
comments.comment
FROM
comments
WHERE
`gid`=303410
LIMIT 1
));
```

(result 34.1612 sec.)
(result  32.2737 sec.)

```
SELECT BENCHMARK(1000000000, (
SELECT
commentstext.comment
FROM
commentsindex,
commentstext
WHERE
`gid`=303410
AND commentsindex.`id` = commentstext.`id`
LIMIT 1
));
```

(result 34.1237 sec.)
(result 34.2914 sec.)

```
SELECT BENCHMARK(1000000000, (
SELECT
commentstext.comment
FROM
commentsindex
INNER JOIN
commentstext
ON commentstext.`id` = commentsindex.`id`
WHERE
`gid`=303410
LIMIT 1
));
```

(result 32.8471 sec.)
(result 34.7079 sec.)

... but now I'm really wondering that it doesn't matter, which table design is in use. *confused*